# Mysql multiple line requests

Tags: mysql, request

I'm new to MySQL and I am facing a little problem that I couldn't find an answer to in any previous thread here, so I was hoping someone could help, okay here it is:

When typing a request on mysql (on the terminal) you can just press enter to make it stand on many lines instead of one, but how do you get back to a previous line ?

I tried the arrow buttons and it didn't work, neither did the backspace button, any help is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can get back to previous lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` command uses the `readline` library. Each input line is edited independently, so once you press <kbd>Return</kbd> you can no longer go back and modify that line. The arrow keys will recall the line, but it's inserted into the current line being edited, and appends to the query.

So the solution is to NOT press <kbd>Return</kbd> until you've finished typing the whole query.

Comment: Alright, sorry to ask again but, suppose you started a multiple line query than you wanted to cancel it, is there a way to do that? in the case of a single line query you can just delete the whole line, but as you explained you can't edit a previous line in the case of multiple lines queries.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to do that, either.

Comment: I just type something that's incorrect syntax, and then `;RETURN`. Then I ignore the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to show previously entered lines in order to send them again, according to the MySQL website, it should work via the up/down keys.

> [...] the up-arrow and down-arrow keys move up and down through the set of previously entered line

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tips.html

Comment: Thank you both very much, Null Void, I was actually referring to what Barmar explained, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome, sorry for the misunderstanding. I realised I may have once I saw Barmar's answer :)